# How to use an external shared library?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am using CMake with C++ and have a shared library in another project.  I have added the lines to my CMake file:

```
find_library(lib1_location NAMES myLib)
message("myLib at: ${lib1_location}")
target_link_libraries(myProject ${lib1_location})
```

and it successfully finds the library.

In my C++ header file, I try to use it just with:

```
#include "myLib.h"
```

but it can't find it. What more do I need to do to use this shared library?  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html

Answer (score 0):

Your CMake code will correctly find the `myLib` library file, but not the library's header files. I imagine you want to add these headers to the *include directories* during compilation of your project. Similar to `find_library()`, you can use [`find_path()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_path.html) to get the include directory containing the header file(s):

```
# Look for a path containing the 'myLib.h' header file, using a 
#   hard-coded hint path if necessary.
find_path(lib1_include_directory "myLib.h"
    PATHS "/path/to/lib1/headers"
)
message("myLib headers at: ${lib1_include_directory}")
# Use this path as an include directory during compilation of myProject.
target_include_directories(myProject PRIVATE ${lib1_include_directory})

find_library(lib1_location NAMES myLib)
message("myLib at: ${lib1_location}")
target_link_libraries(myProject ${lib1_location})
```